# How can I set "Global Keyobard Shortcuts" to the Snap foobar2000?

Tags: shortcut-keys, snap, foobar2000

The new Snap for foobar2000 works excellent, and frankly makes installing foobar2000 on Ubuntu tons of easier.

[image]

But as expected, the "Global hotkeys" option for using Keyboard Shortcuts when minimizing doesn't work.

[image]

Before Snap, it was quite easy to overcome this using Wine commands like this:

[image]

and adding that command as a keyboard shortcut:

[image]

So,

**Is there a way to do something like this with Snap software?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to how the snap has been prepared, this is easy to realize.

The snap package of Foobar defines several contextual actions for the launcher. Inspecting the launcher, `/snap/foobar2000/242/usr/share/applications/foobar2000.desktop`, you can see the command you can use to implement these global shortcut. This is the relevant section of the .desktop file.

```
[Desktop Action PlayPause]
Name=Play/Pause
Exec=foobar2000 -playpause

[Desktop Action Stop]
Name=Stop
Exec=foobar2000 -stop

[Desktop Action Next]
Name=Next
Exec=foobar2000 -next

[Desktop Action Prev]
Name=Prev
Exec=foobar2000 -prev

[Desktop Action Random]
Name=Random
Exec=foobar2000 -rand

[Desktop Action Config]
Name=Preferences
Exec=foobar2000 -config
```

The command `which foobar2000` shows you that the executable is located in `/snap/bin`. To define your shortcut to start/pauze playing, use the command

`/snap/bin/foobar2000 -playpause`

Comment: Thanks! I'm still not that literate on Linux. This is exactly what I was looking for :)